# Override a class used by a library on runtime

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, overriding

I'd like to override a method that one of my 3rd-party library classes is using.

```
public abstract class IndirectClient<C extends Credentials, U extends CommonProfile> extends BaseClient<C, U> {
    private LogoutActionBuilder<U> logoutActionBuilder = new NoLogoutActionBuilder<>();

    @Override
    public final RedirectAction getLogoutAction(final WebContext context, final U currentProfile, final String targetUrl) {
        init(context);
        return logoutActionBuilder.getLogoutAction(context, currentProfile, targetUrl);
    }

}
```

In my case the class `OidcLogoutActionBuilder` that implements `LogoutActionBuilder` interface is called :

```
public class OidcLogoutActionBuilder<U extends OidcProfile> extends InitializableWebObject implements LogoutActionBuilder<U> {

    ...

    //I'd like to override this method
    @Override
    public RedirectAction getLogoutAction(final WebContext context, final U currentProfile, final String targetUrl) {
        init(context);
    }

}
```

I tried to extend the `OidcLogoutActionBuilder` class and override the desired method :

```
public class OidcLogoutActionBuilderCustom extends OidcLogoutActionBuilder<OidcProfile> {

        ...

        //Method overriden
        @Override
        public RedirectAction getLogoutAction(final WebContext context, final OidcProfile currentProfile, final String targetUrl) {
            init2(context);
        }
}
```

It didn't work, `getLogoutAction()` still calls `OidcLogoutActionBuilder` and not `OidcLogoutActionBuilderCustom` on runtime. How can I manage to do that ?

Comment: `final U currentProfile`? I'm sure you declared the parameter as `final OidcProfile currentProfile`?

Comment: @daniu, yes. I edited my question.